# pagination with input field

Tags: php, html, pagination

I am having the following code for pagination

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li <?php if ($products->number == 0) echo "class='active'"; ?>>
        <a <?php if ($products->number != 0): ?> href="index.php?page=0<?php echo(isset($_GET['cid']) ? '&cid=' . $_GET['cid'] : ''); ?>#prdct" <?php endif; ?>>1</a>
      </li>

      <?php if ($products->totalPages > 2) { ?>
      <?php if ($products->number > 3): ?>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">...</a>
      </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php for ($i=( $products->number == 0 ? 1 : $products->number-1); $i
      < $products->number+2 && $i
        < $products->totalPages - 1; $i++) { ?>
          <li <?php if ($products->number == $i) echo "class='active'"; ?>>
            <a <?php if ($products->number != $i): ?> href="index.php?page=<?php echo $i . (isset($_GET['cid']) ? '&cid=' . $_GET['cid'] : ''); ?>#prdct" <?php endif; ?>><?php echo($i + 1); ?></a>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($products->number
          < $products->totalPages - 3): ?>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">...</a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($products->totalPages > 1): ?>
            <li <?php if ($products->number == $products->totalPages) echo "class='active'"; ?>>
              <a <?php if ($products->number != $products->totalPages - 1): ?> href="index.php?page=<?php echo ($products->totalPages - 1) . (isset($_GET['cid']) ? '&cid=' . $_GET['cid'] : ''); ?>#prdct" <?php endif; ?>><?php echo $products->totalPages; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And needs an input field to jump between pages, currently it will look like the following style
[image]

is it possible to add an input field and a button for jumping to another page directly instead of selecting buttons one by one

Comment: use a dropdown field

Comment: my pagination page numbers appears on the address bar too. i just rename the ?page=2 with any page number i want

Comment: @PranavCBalan need the buttons with input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some JavaScript for that

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="pageNo"/>
<button type="button" id="changePage">Change</button>
```

**JS :**

```
var input = document.getElementById('pageNo'),
    button = document.getElementById('changePage'),
    limit = <?php echo $products->totalPages; ?>;

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var page = parseInt(input.value, 10) || 1;
    location.href = 'index.php?page=' + (page <= limit ? page - 1 : limit - 1) + '<?php echo (isset($_GET['cid']) ? '&cid=' . $_GET['cid'] : ''); ?>#prdct'
})
```

Comment: it showing the default page while entering a number and click change button